# `rails c production` returns fe_sendauth while `rails c` works perfectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails application works without errors and writes to and reads from both production(psql) and development(sqlite) databases.

When I try rails console in development environment (`rails c`), works perfectly. However when I try it in production environment (`rails c production`) it returns:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have config for production available in `database.yml`

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: production_database_name
  username: username
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Also, you don't need to pass -e flag for console

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

This will start rails console in production env

Comment: I have configuration for production db, how could my website work in production environment otherwise? I also checked db entries from psql shell. Application can connect to db.

Comment: Problem is not related to this. I actually solved it, but I don't remember how.